# Symfony Amqp Messenger "Call to a Member function get() null"

Tags: php, symfony, amqp, symfony-messenger

My controller

```
$arr = array(
        "key1",
        "key2",
        "key3"
    );
    foreach ($arr as $key) {
        $this->bus->dispatch(new HubspotMessage($key));

    }
```

My Message Handler

```
$key = $hubspotMessage->getKey();

$selectedEntity = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Deal::class)->find(30);
```

I've tried several things but always get an error like this.

```
Error thrown while handling message App\Message\HubspotMessage. Sending for retry #2 using 2000 ms delay. Error: "Call to a member function get() on null"
```

Comment: I think we can't help you without the HubspotMessage itself. But you can debug a little bit more by disabling the retry policy (in messenger.yaml) and once a message has fail, you can use the debug commande `bin/console messenger:failed:show`.

Comment: @Nek I am a dumb. The errorcomes from somewhere else.